# Unable to return ResponseEntity on WebClient.ResponseSpec.toEntity mock

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, mockito, spring-webclient

Test Class

```
@SpringBootTest
class TestClass {

@Mock
private WebClient.ResponseSpec responseMock;


@Test
public void testSampleMethod() {

//responseStr is valid json string
ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity = new ResponseEntity<String>(responseStr, HttpStatus.OK))

when(responseMock.toEntity(String.class)).thenReturn(responseEntity);

}
```

**thenReturn()** gives a compliation error - "Cannot resolve method 'thenReturn(org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.lang.String>)'"

Is mocking ResponseEntity not allowed in Mockito? I can see an [example of same here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mock-rest-template) but it doesn't seem be to be accepted in my case. Is there any alternative way of mocking ResponseEntity.

Answer (score 1):

The [toEntity](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/reactive/function/client/WebClient.ResponseSpec.html#toEntity-java.lang.Class-) methods return `Mono<ResponseEntity<T>>`, so you should return `Mono<ResponseEntity<String>>`

```
when(responseMock.toEntity(String.class)).thenReturn(Mono.just(responseEntity));
```